# bash script - need date command variable

Tags: linux, bash-script

I am trying to create a script that will parse the `/var/log/secure` file for failed login attempts for today's date only and redirect those attempts into a separate file so I can view those attempts only in that file. I am having a problem with getting the script to work with the date command output. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate=$(date '+%D')
mytime=$(date '+%H:%M')
monthday=$(date '+%b %d)
error=$(grep Failed /var/log/secure | grep $monthday >> ~/logs/failed.log
```

With this code, it will not work.  However, if I hard code the date in like this:

```
error=$(grep Failed /var/log/secure | grep 'Feb 28' >> ~/logs/failed.log
```

it works.

How can I make it so that the `$monthday` is the thing grep'd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes:

```
grep Failed /var/log/secure | grep "$monthday" >> ~/logs/failed.log
# .................................^.........^
```

Without the quotes, grep will see **2** arguments -- grep will ignore stdin and search for the string "Feb" in the file "28".
I see an error "grep: 28: no such file or directory"

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I was missing something.  I even tried '$someday' earlier.  LOL

Comment: also, you need to use the double quotes as shown above, in single quotes the variable will not expand